# How do i stop player from continuesly falling when i collide with top block?

Tags: forms, winforms, collision

I am using Windows Form Application and making a simple 2d platformer, with a picturebox that is the player and an array list of pictureboxes that are the blocks.
When i collide with Blocks[i].Top the "player" keeps falling into the top blocks. I think it is becuase

```
{player.Top += 3;}
```

is always happening.

How do i tell the player to stop falling when i collide with the top blocks?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle playerRect = player.ClientRectangle;
            playerRect.X = player.Location.X;
            playerRect.Y = player.Location.Y;
            Rectangle blockRect = blocks[i].ClientRectangle;
            blockRect.X = blocks[i].Location.X;
            blockRect.Y = blocks[i].Location.Y;
            Rectangle Intersection = Rectangle.Intersect(playerRect, blockRect);


            if (jump == true)
            {
                //hur snabbt spelaren faller
                player.Top -= force;
                force -= 1;
            }

            if (player.Top + player.Height >= screen.Height)
            {
                player.Top = screen.Height - player.Height;
                if (jump == true)
                {
                    player.Image = Image.FromFile("gubbe_still.png");

                }
                jump = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player.Top += 3;
            }


            //sid kollision
            if (player.Right > blocks[i].Left &&
                player.Left < blocks[i].Right - player.Width / 2 &&
                player.Bottom > blocks[i].Top)
            {
                right = false;
            }


            //sid kollision
            if (player.Left < blocks[i].Right &&
                player.Right > blocks[i].Left + player.Width / 2 &&
                player.Bottom > blocks[i].Top)
            {
                left = false;
            }


            // top kollision           
            if (player.Right - 5 > blocks[i].Left &&
                player.Right + 5 < blocks[i].Left + blocks[i].Width + player.Width &&
                player.Top + player.Height >= blocks[i].Top &&
                player.Top < blocks[i].Top)

            {
                jump = false;
                force = 0;
                player.Top = blocks[i].Location.Y - player.Height;

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some collision detection issues

```
// top kollision           
if (player.Right - 5 > blocks[i].Left &&
      player.Right + 5 < blocks[i].Left + blocks[i].Width + player.Width &&
      player.Top + player.Height >= blocks[i].Top &&
      player.Top < blocks[i].Top)
```

The first check (player.Right - 5 > blocks[i].Left) will fail if the player is standing off the left side of the block at all. You want something like:

```
// top kollision           
if ((player.Left > blocks[i].Left &&
      player.Left < blocks[i].Right) || 
      (player.Right < blocks[i].Left &&
      player.Right > blocks[i].Left) &&
      player.Top + player.Height >= blocks[i].Top &&
      player.Top < blocks[i].Top)
```